# is the invertible elements of order n $a^n \equiv 1 \pmod m$ in $\mathbb{Z}_m $?

Tags: group-theory, elementary-number-theory

I'm learning number theory and can see that it has many connections to ring theory. So what I was wondering is if the invertible elements of order $n$ are the elements $a$ in $\mathbb{Z}_m$ such that:
$$a^n \equiv 1\pmod{m}$$

And  why/why not?

Comment: Almost, but not quite—consider $a=1$ for example. In addition to $a^n\equiv1\pmod m$, we require that $a^k\not\equiv1\pmod m$ for all $k<n$.

Comment: Oh okay, do you know where I can find a proof/explanation of it? Would like to understand why it is!

Comment: This is really just the definition of "order" in the ring-theory sense, together with the fact that $1$ is the multiplicative unit in $\Bbb Z_m$.

Comment: Ah, haven't learned about order in the context of ring-theory so can't really see the connection yet!

Comment: Or rather, group-theory, since it is really about the group $\mathbb{Z}_m^{\times}$ only.